# Как спарсить данные 3х разных классов?

Tags: java

Добрый день.Получаю даннеы от сервера .Есть 3 класса `class Strundent{},class BankInvoice{},class OpenCredit{}`  и получаю их даннеы к 1 юзеру.В каждом из этих классов по 10 полей .да я могу данные записать в них но в этих классах есть поля которые мне нужны не будут.Что мне делать ?создать ещё один обьект с этими полями ? или наследоваться от них ?

Comment: заполняйте уже существующие объекты. С наследование надо быть аккуратным, даже если вы унаследуютесь от одного, то вам придется ещё дописать 20 полей и к ним геттеры и сеттеры (т.е. продублировать существующий код). Вообще вам стоит дописать зачем вам это? Потом что ответ на ваш вопрос - дело вкуса

Comment: @Виктор просто хочу знать как правильнее быть в таких ситуациях

Comment: исходя из задачи